# PHP: Automatically Saving a dynamic PDF to the remote server using DOMPDF

Tags: php, pdf-generation, dompdf

I am using the dompdf library to create my table based PDF and I can view it online or I can have it download to the users folder of choice.

But what I would like to do is have it save it to the remote server( i dont need it to be save to the users PC), like an automatically upload script that would create the file then upload it to the remote server, so i can then use it within my application later on.

is it possible to point the $_FILES["file"] script say so fetch the php page that creates the pdf and it then uploads it from there.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do one thing like below which i am doing for my application. First create a folder in your server under the root directory for example. Then change read write permissions to that folder using chmod command.

Then get all the code in `$html` string.

```
$dompdf->load_html($html);    
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
$file_location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."app_folder_name/pdfReports/".$pdf_name.".pdf";
file_put_contents($file_location,$pdf);
```

Where `pdfReports` is the folder which i created to save all the pdf's. You can change to your folder name.

Comment: Thanks for this the file_put_contents has done the trick, i works on my simple page now to get it to work on my more complicated dynamic page, but thanks also thanks to Stephan, kufudo and Vincent Kelleher

Comment: i just need to create one page but the table will be long, but looking into using PHPExcel to do the heavy work then using dompdf to convert, which i am doing now, will just need to implement the same fiel upload code to it and it should all be done.

Comment: are you free to talk for 5 minutes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24439/discussion-between-simon-davies-and-venkat)

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from PHP manual :

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the [fopen
>   wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) have been enabled.See [fopen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for more details on how to
>   specify the filename. See the [Supported Protocols and Wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) for
>   links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have,
>   notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they
>   may provide.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

Is it feasible to create the PDF directly on the server instead, and let the client download it if he needs it? If so, you could use wkhtmltppdf to convert any HTML page into a PDF on the server and save it and/or stream it to the client.

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the [FTP functions of PHP](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.ftp.php) ?