# PHP Excel: Saving created PDF to remote server and not user downlaod

Tags: php, phpexcel

This is similar to my previous question re ([DOMPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851090/php-automatically-saving-a-dynamic-pdf-to-the-remote-server-using-dompdf)), the difference is that now i am using PHPExcel, to create the PDF.

I have tried the file_put method but it downloads an empty PDF. SO where am i going wrong or can this not be done?

below is my end code that outputs the fiel and what i have tried

```
  header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="TestSheet.pdf"');
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
  $objWriter->save('php://output');

  $file_location = $save_Path;
  file_put_contents($file_location,$objWriter);
  exit;
```

It seems that once its been saved its clearing the data so hence the blank PDF

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discard the headers.... they're all about telling the web browser to expect a PDF file, but you're not sending anything back to the browser (let alone a PDF file).

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

is telling PHPExcel to send the generated PDF directly to the web browser.... you say you don't want to do that, but to save to a remote server instead.

You'll need to intercept the results from $objWriter->save() so it doesn't go to the browser. Capture it using output buffering:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
ob_start();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
$myPdfData = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Then you've captured the PDF datastream in $myPdfData and can then do:

```
file_put_contents($file_location, $myPdfData);
```

Note that this is likely to be memory-hungry

Comment: Much appreciated for this i would never have got that, but great thanks

Comment: @Mark Baker: Great answer. It worked out for me. What do you meant by memory hungry? I created pdf file from excel file using Ajax request. When my generated Excel file contains more than 50 rows, the ajax call get aborted. I don't know why. But when I try to create pure xls file alone, it is working.